# R function to identify elements same as previous element

Tags: r

```
v = c(1,0,1, 1,1,2, 1,2,2, 0,0,1)
```

I'm looking for a function that will give me:

```
c(F,F,F, T,T,F, F,F,T, F,T,F)
```

I.e. true at element ix if v[ix] equals element v[ix-1].

By the way, `duplicated(v)` is not what I want, as it compares to all earlier rows, and gives me:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do this

```
v <- c(1,0,1, 1,1,2, 1,2,2, 0,0,1)
c(FALSE, v[-1] == v[-length(v)])
##  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
## [11]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for this (and to Hong for the same idea). I've confirmed that it works.

Answer (score 4):

```
v[-1] == v[-length(v)]
```

Note that your requirement is undefined for `v[1]`.

Comment: Congrats @HongOoi on 10K! How does all that power feel? :)

Comment: @arun _I can see dead posts_

Answer (score 3):

If you have only numeric values then you could also use diff function. If 0 -> equal, else not equal

```
 v = c(1,0,1, 1,1,2, 1,2,2, 0,0,1)
 diff(v)
 ## [1] -1  1  0  0  1 -1  1  0 -2  0  1
 !as.logical(diff(v))
 ## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Aha, interesting idea. I suspect it might be more efficient. BTW, it needs to be `c( FALSE, !as.logical(diff(v)) )` to get all 12 entries. Or `!as.logical( c(0,diff(v)) )`